# What causes servos to get damaged from high voltage?

Tags: motor, servo

I have 6 volt continuous servos. I needed to run them, but had no 6 volt power source nearby so I tried using a 9 volt 280mah rechargeable battery. The motor made weird sounds, but didn't work? I checked later and it still works with 6 volts. What caused it to malfunction?

Answer (score 1):

The microcontroller inside a servo is not rated to run off 9V. Supplying that much voltage can cause it to be permanently damaged.

Comment: What could've caused the battery to heat up?

Comment: The fact that the servo was drawing more current due to the increased voltage.

Comment: There may even be internal voltage clamoing circuit elements on the board or in the controller IC that (try to) limit the voltage to 6V (for a 4.5-6V servo) and these may have been shunting a lot of current from the battery.  You may have been lucky and not done permanent damage this time.  Electrolytic capacitors may also be over voltaged and suffer damage, leak or even pop open.